# Using Passed URL Parameters in @wire calls

Tags: lightning-web-components

LWC Component question.  I have an Id field:

```
export default class CustomerQuoteAcceptDecline extends LightningElement {

_quoteId;  // record Id
```

which I populate from URL parameters in the connectedCallback():

```
    connectedCallback() {

    let parmMap = LightningUtil.getURLParameters();

    LightningUtil.log('parmMap size:' + parmMap.size);
    LightningUtil.log('HASH_PARM:' + parmMap.get(this.HASH_PARM));
    LightningUtil.log('QUOTE_PARM:' + parmMap.get(this.QUOTE_PARM));
    LightningUtil.log('ACTION_PARM:' + parmMap.get(this.ACTION_PARM));

    if(parmMap.size > 0) {            

        if(parmMap.has(this.HASH_PARM)) {
            this._loadHash = parmMap.get(this.HASH_PARM);
        }
        if(parmMap.has(this.QUOTE_PARM)) {
            this._quoteId = parmMap.get(this.QUOTE_PARM);
        }
        if(parmMap.has(this.ACTION_PARM)) {
            let action = parmMap.get(this.ACTION_PARM);
            if(action == this.ACCEPT_TENDER) {
                this._isAccept = true;
                this._isDecline = false;
            }
            else {
                this._isAccept = false;
                this._isDecline = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see the parameters populated in the console no problem.

However this @wire function fails:

```
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$_quoteId', fields: [QUOTE_ID_FIELD, LOAD_FIELD]})
wiredQuote({ error, data }) {

    if(data) {
        this._quote = data.fields;
        this._loadId = this._quote[LOAD_FIELD.fieldApiName].value;
        LightningUtil.log('wiredQuote Success');
    }
    else if (error) {
        LightningUtil.logError(this, error);
        this._isError = true;
        LightningUtil.log('wiredQuote Fail');
    }
}
```

I see "wiredQuote Fail" in the console.

Any idea what is going on here?  Is the @wire jumping the gun before the _quoteId parameter is populated by connectedCallback()?  Or is reactivity somehow goofing it up?  Do @wire functions invoke (too soon) when the reactive parameter is (still) null?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a weird problem with parameters starting with `_` - faced before. Can you try removing underscore?

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to be working alright for me even though I have the `_` in place in the name of `_quoteId`. I also tried adding a `timeout` function of 1500ms before setting the `_quoteId` and the wire responds perfectly as soon as the `_quoteId` value gets populated. What is the `error` that you are getting when the wire fails? Is it saying that `_quoteId` is undefined?

Comment: Thanks folks for trying to help.  I get "The requested resource does not exist...." in the console.  I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that I pass the 15-character ID in as _quoteId not the 18-character Id....

Comment: @DaveC That should not matter. Can you load the record in Salesforce for that id? Is it a valid Salesforce Id? Maybe the record was deleted? Or perhaps it's a permissions issue for the user running the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lwc, @wire called before the connected callback(),

so set the `_quoteId` value in the constructor()

so, below code will work:

```
export default class CustomerQuoteAcceptDecline extends LightningElement {
@api _quoteId;  // record Id

constructor() {
    super();
    let parmMap = LightningUtil.getURLParameters();

    LightningUtil.log('parmMap size:' + parmMap.size);
    LightningUtil.log('HASH_PARM:' + parmMap.get(this.HASH_PARM));
    LightningUtil.log('QUOTE_PARM:' + parmMap.get(this.QUOTE_PARM));
    LightningUtil.log('ACTION_PARM:' + parmMap.get(this.ACTION_PARM));

    if(parmMap.size > 0) {            

        if(parmMap.has(this.HASH_PARM)) {
            this._loadHash = parmMap.get(this.HASH_PARM);
        }
        if(parmMap.has(this.QUOTE_PARM)) {
            this._quoteId = parmMap.get(this.QUOTE_PARM);
        }
        if(parmMap.has(this.ACTION_PARM)) {
            let action = parmMap.get(this.ACTION_PARM);
            if(action == this.ACCEPT_TENDER) {
                this._isAccept = true;
                this._isDecline = false;
            }
            else {
                this._isAccept = false;
                this._isDecline = true;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: That does not matter. As per documentation: `"If a reactive variable changes, the wire service provisions new data."` Meaning that as soon as `connectedCallback()` finishes running and sets the `_quoteId` variable the `wired` method will run again.

Comment: But does the @wire run initially when the parameter is null?  That would bomb out...

Comment: @DaveC it runs initially yes, and then it runs again once the value gets set from the `connectedCallback`

Comment: Karthiba -- Thanks you were correct!  I moved the parm reading to the constructor and am good to go.  Thanks again.

Comment: Arthlete -- Thanks for your help also!